# How do I add a date and institutional affiliation to the Fibeamer theme's titlepage?

Tags: beamer

[Fibeamer Beamer theme](https://www.fi.muni.cz/lemma/projekty/fithesis3/#fibeamer)

This theme has only Title of the presentation, subtitle and author name. I want to add date and affiliation. Thanks for the help.

```
documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[microtype,faculty=fsps]{fibeamer} 
\author{Karthik}
\title{Title of the document}
\date{8.10.2017}
\institute{My institute}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I took the original theme's style file from Overleaf - can be accessed [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/fibeamer-for-the-faculty-of-sports-studies-at-the-masaryk-university-in-brno/qpqhgjbmwyng). Edited it to remove the university logo. My output file looks like this.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please add some code to your question ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)).

Comment: @Bobyandbob Added MWE. Please have a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your own title page and add the missing information wherever you want it to go. In the following example, I added it after the author:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[microtype,faculty=fsps]{fibeamer} 
\author{Karthik}
\title{Title of the document}
\date{8.10.2017}
\institute{My institute}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{%
  % This is slide 0
  \setcounter{framenumber}{0}

  % Input the university logo
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    remember picture,
    overlay,
    xshift=0.5\fibeamer@lengths@logowidth,
    yshift=0.5\fibeamer@lengths@logoheight
  ]
    \node at (0,0) {
      \fibeamer@includeLogo[
        width=\fibeamer@lengths@logowidth,
        height=\fibeamer@lengths@logoheight
      ]};
  \end{tikzpicture}

  % Input the title
  \usebeamerfont{title}%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{title}%
  \begin{minipage}[b][2\baselineskip][b]{\textwidth}%
    \raggedright\inserttitle
  \end{minipage}
  \vskip-.5\baselineskip

  % Input the dashed line
  \begin{pgfpicture}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}
    \pgfsetroundcap
    \pgfsetdash{{0pt}{4pt}}{0cm}

    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0mm}{0mm}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\textwidth}{0mm}}

    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  \end{pgfpicture}
  \vfill
  % Input the subtitle
  \usebeamerfont{subtitle}%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}%
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \raggedright%
    \insertsubtitle%
  \end{minipage}\vskip.25\baselineskip

  % Input the author's name
  \usebeamerfont{author}%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{author}%
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \raggedright%
    \insertauthor\newline%
    \insertinstitute\newline%
    \insertdate%
  \end{minipage}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]